# MeshLab Command Line switches

Tags: meshlab

is the a list of all command line switches that one can reference to?

It is otherwise hard to use it via command line and one is forced to dig through source code.

I am interested in Linux release, if there are any differences, but anyhow any reference will do.

Binary has no --help implemented so...

Thanks in advance

Comment: -h actually implemented but not giving much info.                                        if (argc > 1){
  const QString helpOpt1 = "-h";
  const QString helpOpt2 = "--help";
  const QString versOpt1 = "-v";
  const QString versOpt2 = "--version";
  if(helpOpt1==argv[1] || helpOpt2==argv[1]) {
   std::cout <<
      "Usage:\n"
      "meshlab <meshfile>\n"
      "Look at http://www.meshlab.net\n"
      "for a longer documentation\n";
   return 0;
  }
  if (versOpt1==argv[1] || versOpt2==argv[1]){
   std::cout << "MeshLab " << meshlab::meshlabVersion() << "\n";
   return 0;
  }
 }

Comment: Just realized from source code that GUI is created anyhow,  MeshLabApplication app(argc, argv);
 etc. so how to run some calculations without GUI?

Answer (score 2):

MeshLab is a GUI application.
It can accept arguments just in order to support "Open with..." shortcuts on OSs.
If you are looking for command line tools, please check [pymeshlab](https://pymeshlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).